# avoid multiple remove events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I use backbone version 1.0.0 & underscore js.
From my collection , i remove models that match some criteria.

```
myCollection.remove(myCollection.where({filterId: "1"}));
```

This will remove all the models inside my collection having filterId attribute == "1".

Now this is causing multiple change events for "remove" being fired when I have more than 1 model matching the criteria.

I want it to be fired only once when all matching models are removed. 
Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to limit the remove event only once as Backbone triggers every time when a model is removed from a collection.

Instead you can filter the collection and listen for reset event.

```
   var filtered = myCollection.filter(function(model) {
      return model.get("filterId") != 1;
    });

   myCollection.reset(filtered);
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Calling `reset` at the end for filtering the result is the good way to avoid multiple `remove` events in backbone.